# exe icon is changing automatically when build the application in visual studio

Tags: mfc

I want to change my application exe icon from default. Now when I copied the new icon with same name as default icon had in "res" folder of application. when I compiled it's exe came with new icon.

But at the same time when I copied another icon with another name in "res" folder and include it in my project. Now rese folder has two icons(one icon is for application's icon). Now when I compiled my application that time exe come with new icon. But it should come with old icon as IDR_MAINFRAME holds.

Please help me out.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MFC - Replacing default application icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150784/mfc-replacing-default-application-icon).

Comment: Yes I did in the same way but not changing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit the .rc icon file directly. I think it's already write in duplicate post.